# android.synthetic library isn't being recognized in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

In my Activity.kt class, the synthetic isn't being recognized in the import

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic...
```

I have included the following in my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

When trying it import, it will recognize extensions and parcel

```
import kotlinx.android.extensions...
import kotlinx.android.parcel...
```

So why is synthetic the only one not being recognized?

Other info:
I have tried invalidating caches and restarting.
I have another computer that also has this android studio project (Same gradle versions and everything). Everything works fine there.

Edit:

1. I understand the current way to do it is to use data binding. But this is just a project we need to sustain, not improve and upgrade. We have a custom sdk (added many years ago) in the project that is making it hard to upgrade gradle and modernize.
2. The project, even though synthetic is not recognized, is building and uploading fine. I just want to remove these red lines of error.

Any advice on how to start trouble shooting would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not only `Synthetics`, `kotlin-android-extentions` as a whole has been deprecated in favor of _standalone plugins_. The replacement for `Synthetics` is [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding), and the replacement for `Parcel` is [Parcelize](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize).

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your comments. I understand migration to view binding is the way to go. However, this is a project we just need to sustain, not improve and upgrade.
Again, this project is working on another computer with the same kotlin and gradle versions. So I'd just like to know what I can do to troubleshoot this and get it to work.

Comment: @Tyler V 
Your suggestion to downgrade Android Studio worked. I am now using version 3.6, and it is now recognizing the synthetic. 

If you wouldn't mind, answer the question so I can give you the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synthetics were deprecated and removed in the latest version of Android Studio (Chipmunk). The recommendation is to [migrate to using view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration). If you cannot do that, then you'll need to use an older version of Android Studio.

Migrating to view binding from synthetics is generally straightforward, so that's the better long term solution of course, but changing the IDE version is a quick short term solution.

Even projects in maintenance mode require occasional maintenance - like dealing with deprecations.